# Choice Django - criar choices a partir de um model

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma Model para definir um perfil de acesso ao sistema. A partir da escolha, serão liberadas funções especificas dentro do sistema.

Estou usando uma `CHOICE` e, a principio, só temos esses perfis, porém fico pensando se futuramente, pode ser necessário criar algum novo perfil de acesso, então a minha pergunta é, eu consigo atualizar uma `CHOICE` em tempo de execução, criando uma página de atualização para o próprio usuário do sistema criar um novo Perfil ou toda vez que isso for necessário eu preciso ajustar diretamente no código?

Segue o código:

```
class permissao(models.Model):
PERMISSAO_CHOICE = (
    ('01', 'Admin'),
    ('02', 'Financeiro'),
    ('03', 'Secretaria'),
    ('04', 'Membro'),
)

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
codigopermissao = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False, choices=PERMISSAO_CHOICE, verbose_name="Código do Perfil")
nomepermissao = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, verbose_name="Tipo de Perfil")
```

Comment: olá , eu editei a pergunta para ela representar melhor a dúvida, também removi alguns fragmentos de texto para a pergunta ser mais direta. Se acha que o texto editado não ficou bom, você pode editar a pergunta você mesmo. Basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/585270/edit)

Comment: Show. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo apenas a pergunta, se implementou da forma que está na pergunta, a resposta é: Sim.

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando um modelform para renderizar um form e sobreescrever o campo que deseja com a lista de escolhas possíveis.

Desta forma ao ser necessário adicionar mais uma opção (uma nova escolha), então basta adicionar uma nova linha na tabela que mapeia a sua entidade (model) no modelo relacional.

No código abaixo eu criei uma nova classe chamada `Papel` que cada linha desta entidade, vai popular o select/option correspondente ao campo `códigopermissão`.

Segue uma implementação, utilizando o seu código como base:

```
class permissao(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigopermissao = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False, verbose_name="Código do Perfil")
    nomepermissao = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, verbose_name="Tipo de Perfil")

class Papel(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Para isso vai ser necessário criar um ModelForm e sobre-escrever o campo `codigopermissão` para que ele seja populado de acordo com os dados do Model Papel.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PermissaoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = permissao
        fields = ['codigopermissao', 'nomepermissao']

    codigopermissao = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Papel.objects.all(),
        required=True,
    )
```

Repare que aqui o nível de indentação da variável `codigopermissao` deve ser o mesmo da class Meta, ele pertence à classe `PermissãoForm`.

Após esses passos será necessário rodar o `makemigrations` e o `migrate`.
Isso vai criar a entidade que acabamos de criar.

Agora basta criar as linhas com a opções de papel para serem listadas em seu formulário. Eu fiz isso via o Django shell (escolha o método mais adequado).

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Veja também a documentação da [classe Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

Uma versão mais detalhada pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://danizavtz.com.br/choice-django-criar-choices-a-partir-de-um-model-model/)

Comment: Amigo, que resposta top demais. Muito obrigado viu. Vou estudar e tentar implementar essa sugestão.
Como disse, ainda estou iniciando, mas acredito que consegui entender a sua lógica.
Obrigado.